# gtest setup teardown TestEnvironment - issue with class variable

Tags: c++, static, googletest, teardown

I have another gtest where I do the following and it works fine:

```
TEST(TEST1, TestName)
{
ClassName env;
const String original = env(Con::WorkingDir);

Con c = env;
}
```

However, I want this to be set for another gtest class and hold throughout the entire test fixture.  However, I'm getting this error message:

> Call of an object of class type without appropriate operator or
>   conversion functions to pointer-to-function type.

I'm looking at [initialize gtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593762/how-to-initialize-constant-string-for-multiple-tests-in-google-test), and I'm not sure what I'm missing for this.  It could be use of static variables I'm not familiar with.  I don't want ClassName to be static, though.

What am I doing wrong with this?

```
//this is intended to setup env to use in teardown.
class TestEnvironment : public ::testing::Environment {
public:
 static String getEn() {
   ClassName env;
   static const String sString = env(Con::WorkingDir);  //env has the error message here
   return sString;
 }
}

class UnitTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
virtual void SetUp() {
   //
}

virtual void TearDown() {
  //set env back to initial value
  getEn();
  //process env info;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give us more details about class `ClassName`. Statement like `static const String sString = env(Con::WorkingDir);` can compile if `env` is a function object, and the error message suggest that it is not. I would suggest that you edit your question by adding a definition of `ClassName`.

Comment: I got it working by removing the static const

Comment: The class is not a function object.  I never heard of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UnitTest : public ::testing::Test {  //can't use Environment here because of name conflict in our code, although that was used by static const variable setup in example link.
public:
 String orig;
}

class UnitTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
virtual void SetUp() {
   orig = code;
}

virtual void TearDown() {
  //process orig;
}
```

It turned out that even though our code was looking for a const string, we don't have to save it as const.